# Shutdown Spring MVC App that was run on CMD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I have a simple Spring MVC project I created and I package it as a war file. I tried running it on CMD using command "javaw -jar filename.war"

it run successfully and i can access the URL but now I can't figure out how I can stop it. Can anyone please point me out to how it should be done?

TIA.

Comment: ctrl+C should stop it in CMD